# I am getting this error "Cannot use namespace 'Observable' as a type.ts(2709)" in rxjs 7.4 using Angular 13

Tags: angular, rxjs

With the following:

```
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

with rxjs in a typings.d.ts file like so:

```
declare module 'rxjs';
```

I am getting this vscode lint error:

```
Cannot use namespace 'Observable' as a type.ts(2709)
```

when I do this:

```
 async getCoinData(serviceName: string): Observable<any>{.....}
```

anybody knows the fix for this?

Comment: try importing from
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

Comment: Unless you're using an advanced configuration, you shouldn't need to declare the module in a typings file. RxJS is bundled with its own typings. Not sure if that's causing the issue, but it's definitely not something I need. You could try wiping out your node_modules folder and installing again.

Comment: @Damian...yep for Angular 13 rxjs is v 7.4 and it behaves differently....for now you need the typings...apparently

Comment: @Danish  import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx'; gives error:  Cannot find module 'rxjs/Rx' or its corresponding type declarations.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do a change in your tsconfig.json file, to turn allowSyntheticDefaultImports to true

```
"compilerOptions": {
 "allowSyntheticDefaultImports":true
},
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowSyntheticDefaultImports

Comment: I see no reason why this is applicable here....a little explanation would help.

Comment: This doesn't work. I get the error even if this compiler option is enabled

Answer (score 0):

I've created a file (types/index.d.ts) and added this:

```
type Observable<T> = unknow;
```